# Self referencing entity in NHibernate gives object references an unsaved transient instance exception

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a self referencing entity named Category.
A category may have one or more child categories. A category may also have no childs.

I have made the entity and mapping but I keep getting this exception.

> NHibernate.TransientObjectException : object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or
>   set cascade action for the property to something that would make it
>   autosave.

Am I doing something wrong with the mapping part?
Is it possible to save all Parent and Child objects at once?
Any help would be appreciated.

Following is the Code

**POCO**

```
public class Category
{
    private ICollection<Topic> _topics;
    private ICollection<Category> _childCategory;
    private ICollection<Media> _media;
    private Category _parentCategory;

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual Category ParentCategory
    {
        get { return _parentCategory ?? (_parentCategory = new Category()); }
        protected set { _parentCategory = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategory
    {
        get { return _childCategory ?? (_childCategory = new List<Category>()); }
        protected set { _childCategory = value; }
    }


    public virtual void AddChild(Category childCategory)
    {
        childCategory.ParentCategory = this;
    }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
public class CategoryMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<Category>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Category> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(c => c.Name).Length(30);
        mapping.Map(c => c.Description).Length(160);
        mapping.References(x => x.ParentCategory)
            .Cascade.None()
            .Column("ParentCategoryId");
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.ChildCategory)
            .Inverse().Cascade.All()
            .KeyColumn("ParentCategoryId");
    }
}
```

**Test**
I am creating parent and child categories and trying to save all of them at once.

```
public void CanSaveAllNewObjectGraphFromCategory() {
    #region Categories and Child
    var categories = new sq.Category()
    {
        Description = "Category1",
        IsActive = true,
        Name = "Categoy1"
    };

    var childCat = new List<sq.Category>() {
        new sq.Category(){
            Description = "ChildCategory1",
            IsActive = true,
            Name = "CCategoy1"
        },
        new sq.Category(){
            Description = "ChildCategory2",
            IsActive = true,
            Name = "CCategoy2"
        }
    };

    foreach (var item in childCat)
    {
        categories.AddChild(item);
    }
    #endregion

    using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        _catRepo.AddNewCategory(categories);
        tx.Commit(); // Error occurs when commit is executed.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message gave you two options:

- Save the transient instance before flushing
- Set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave

The first option is straightforward: simply save each instance before commiting the transaction

```
using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
{
  foreach(var category in categories)
  {
     _session.SaveOrUpdate(category);
  }
  _catRepo.AddNewCategory(categories);
  tx.Commit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We would need to to assign both sides of references

```
public virtual void AddChild(Category childCategory)
{
    childCategory.ParentCategory = this;
    // add to collection as well
   _childCategory.Add(childCategory);
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same exception after assigning the other side of the reference.